# onClick on sub <li> react

Tags: javascript, list, reactjs

I want to add sub categories with react on a list, but when i click on sub cat, i have two events : First on sub and second on parent category.

How can i have only child category ?

There is my actual code :

```
getList(myList){
    return myList.map((item) => {
        let subList = '';
        if (item.hasSub){
            subList = (<ul>{this.getList(item.sub)}</ul>)
        }
        return (
        <li onClick={() => {this.props.clicHandler(item.id)}}>{item.title}<div>{subList}</div></li>);
    })
}
```

I'm using recursive method to create my list.
My actual array is like this :

```
this.list.push({id: 1, title:'coucou' , hasSub: false});
this.list.push({id: 2, title:'toto' , hasSub: false});
this.list.push({id: 3, title: 'cat', sub: [{id:4, title:'titi' , hasSub: false}, {id:5, title:'tutu' , hasSub: false}] , hasSub: true});
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [click events "bubble" up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) to parent elements. The solution is to call [`Event.prototype.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on it.

In the below snippet I've added a `clickHandler` method to the component, and in `getList` I pass both the event (`evt`) and `item.id` to it. In that method I call `evt.stopPropagation()` before calling `this.props.clickHandler`. However, you could also do this in the parent component's `clickHandler` method, or within `getList`. Choose whatever best suits your use case.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
  }
  
  render() {
    return <ul>{this.getList(this.props.items)}</ul>;
  }

  getList(list) {
    return list.map((item) => {
      const subList = item.hasSub && (<ul>{this.getList(item.sub)}</ul>);
      return (
        <li key={item.id} onClick={evt => {this.clickHandler(evt, item.id)}}>{item.title}<div>{subList}</div></li>
      );
    });
  }
  
  clickHandler(evt, itemId) {
    // Stop event propagatation before calling handler passed in props
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.props.clickHandler(itemId);
  }
}

const data = [
  { id: 'a', title: 'A', hasSub: false },
  { id: 'b', title: 'B', hasSub: true, sub: [
    { id: 'b1', title: 'B1', hasSub: true, sub: [
      { id: 'b1a', title: 'B1a', hasSub: false },
    ] },
    { id: 'b2', title: 'B2', hasSub: false },
  ] },
  { id: 'c', title: 'C', hasSub: true, sub: [
    { id: 'c1', title: 'C1', hasSub: false },
    { id: 'c2', title: 'C2', hasSub: false },
  ] },
];

function clickHandler(itemId) {
  console.log('clicked item', itemId);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App items={data} clickHandler={clickHandler}/>, document.querySelector('div'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

P.S. Your code is excellent, but might I recommend a somewhat more "React way"  to render nested items?

What your component's `render` method does is call a **`getItems` function** that in turn calls itself, recursively. However, if you recall that most React components can themselves be thought of as functions, you can refactor your code so that your `render` method instead renders an **`<Items>` component** that recursively renders instances of itself.

This approach tends to yield smaller, functional components that are more reusable and easier to test. Take a look in the snippet below.

```js
const Items = ({items, onClick}) => (
  <ul>
    {items.map(item => (
      <li key={item.id} onClick={evt => onClick(evt, item.id)}>
        {item.title}
        {item.hasSub && <Items items={item.sub} onClick={onClick}/>}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);

const data = [
  { id: 'a', title: 'A', hasSub: false },
  { id: 'b', title: 'B', hasSub: true, sub: [
    { id: 'b1', title: 'B1', hasSub: true, sub: [
      { id: 'b1a', title: 'B1a', hasSub: false },
    ] },
  ] },
];

function clickHandler(evt, itemId) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  console.log('clicked item', itemId);
}

ReactDOM.render(<Items items={data} onClick={clickHandler}/>, document.querySelector('div'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Yes you're right ! It's just test code, so my code is a little dirty, but i'll think about when i'll turn it to real code :)
And thank you for you're first part of code ! I what i want !

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the event propagation :

```
getList(myList){
    return myList.map((item) => {
        let subList = '';
        if (item.hasSub){
            subList = (<ul>{this.getList(item.sub)}</ul>)
        }
        return (
        <li onClick={(event) => {event.preventDefault(); this.props.clicHandler(item.id)}}>{item.title}<div>{subList}</div></li>);
    })
}
```

This way the first item to catch the click will stop the click propagation.

Comment: BTW you also need to use the **key** attribute when building a list of elements